# Automatically open google chrome, click button, and close chrome C# WinForms

Tags: c#, .net, windows, forms, html

I've got a task as I've written in subject. I need to open google chrome with a web page and then I want to click button and close chrome. I want it in a Windows Form .net 4.0 and written in C#. I've tried to do something like that:

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"chrome.exe", "webpage");

and this is working well, but I have no idea how to force application to click button on this page and close chrome.

Thanks for any help

Comment: I think you could do this more easily with something like [GreaseMonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-Us/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/)

Comment: You want to close the browser displaying your webpage by a button on windows form? Am I correct?

Comment: Wouldn't you be better off just using HttpClient to send the request that Chrome would?  Use something like Fiddler to get the exact request....

Comment: Syed -> it is not important how it is closed - it can be like you said or no matter how, Dan -> Yes If you think that could be better please help me how could i start with. Do you get for example a tutorial or link to any materials?

Comment: Why do you need it to be chrome?  Couldn't you just use a WebBrowser Control in Windows Forms?

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch The builtin WebBrowser control is a very poor browser, perhaps comparable to IE on Windows Mobile. But it is way beyond a current browser like FF or Chrome, or even IE on Windows. "nobody" uses WebBrowser, while FF/Chrome/IE/... are in fierce competition to be used by billions of users on demanding web sites. Currently I am struggling to use WebBrowser to print a stupid html table, but I am not getting nice page breaks. I am looking here for techiques to send the html from my WinForms app to Chrome or FF or IE in order to get decent printouts, eliminating the use of WebBrowser

Comment: @Roland - To open a page and click a button doesn't seem like any kind of major functional need.  Nobody would be looking at the page, who cares how it renders?  Having said that, if you can't get a simple html table to work in it, then something is seriously wrong with your html.  The built-in WebBrowser uses the IE rendering engine, so anything IE can do, it can do.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch You have a point because the html validator at w3.org did find errors, hence the upvote. However, after fixing those, WebBrowser and FF still show the same print bugs, and IE and Chrome print just fine. Conclusion stays that IE is significantly better than WebBrowser. If you say WebBrowser is IE, then I mean WebBrowser may be based on an old version of IE. We are working here with .NET Framework 4.5.1 which is from 2013, which is in browser terms "very old". But upgrading to 4.7.2 of 2018 did not fix these WebBrowser bugs

Answer (score 3):

The best way for you to do that is create a small HTML file that will do that for you with the  Javascript. That way you can open specifically that file within the chrome and it will do it for you. Let me know if you need specific code. I had to do that several months ago.

```
    public static void TryWebBrowser()
    {
        bool _jsLoaded = false;
        string _directory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;

        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo _sinfo = new    
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(_directory + "loginFile.html");
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(_sinfo);

        while (_jsLoaded == false) 
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process[] _runningProcesses = 
            System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses();
            foreach (System.Diagnostics.Process _p in _runningProcesses)
            {
                if (_p.MainWindowTitle.Contains("Jaspersoft"))
                {
                    _jsLoaded = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

        }

    }
```

Kind of like this.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Launching Jaspersoft</title>
    <script src="other.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function submitForm() {
            document.getElementById("j_username").value = uid
            document.getElementById("j_password").value = pwd
            document.loginForm.action = action
            document.loginForm.submit()
        }


    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="submitForm()">
    <form name="loginForm" method="post" action="">
      <input type="hidden" value="" name="j_username" id="j_username" />
      <input type="hidden" value="" name="j_password" id="j_password" />

    </form>

  </body>
</html>
```

The other.js contained dynamically written uid and password variables nothing else.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
```

Write this in the button click event:

```
Process[] AllProcess = Process.GetProcesses();
            foreach (var process in AllProcess)
            {
                if (process.MainWindowTitle != "")
                {
                    string s = process.ProcessName.ToLower();
                    if (s == "chrome" )
                        process.Kill();
                }
            }
```

Adapted from:
http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/794195/Close-the-all-browser-windows-IE-google-chrome-fir
**EDIT:**
The above code takes care of the closing part. However, for clicking a button
 it would be surprising if Chrome would expose the methods like the button click in a simple way to external applications.
 You may need to write an extension see: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions of your own or you would have to open your web page via the web browser control in win forms and capture the event through it.

Comment: Ok, now I know how open and how close the chrome - but how could I click correct button on page?

Comment: I understand what you need to do but I would be surprised if  Chrome would expose the methods like the button click in a simple  way to external applications. You may need to write an extension see :http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/index.html  of your own or you would have to open your web page via the web browser control in win forms and capture the event through it.

Comment: Make the browser window the active window. Then use SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}"); if the default button is the requested one. Or else add some "{TAB}" to get to the requested button

Answer (score 0):

I do not know your full requirements but I think you may want to look on some automation tools, like selenium [Selenium](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/)

You can take a look on the getting started here https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/GettingStarted

It is written in Java but they have .net api too:
http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/dotnet/index.html

Hope this helps.